# Node js readFile toString making sounds

Tags: javascript, node.js, tostring, readfile

I have just some basic HTML:

```
[...]<body>

<p>Some Text</p>
<img src="path/nodejs.jpg?">

</body>[...]
```

And a basic node js function as request callback for server.

```
 fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, content){
       if (err) throw err;

        // * console.log(content.toString());

        var mime = require('mime').lookup(filePath);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', mime + "; charset=utf-8");
        res.end(content);
    });
```

I wanted to console.log (* line) the content but when I did this, my laptop began beeping booping i.e making sounds. So why does it happen?

Comment: there's a BEL char (7?) that causes a beep when viewed on the console, from back in the early ASCII days... since your JPEG contains probably all the ASCII chars somewhere in there, it causes beeps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary byte of `7`, seen as ASCII text via the console produces a beep.

Example: `console.log(String.fromCharCode(7))`

Readup more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character

These days, encountering it's more often an annoying accident than something useful.

Comment: So it is literally converting this image to sounds?

Comment: certain bytes of the image are being mis-interpreted. you can probably find `"ABC"` in a large image as well, even though it's not a picture of the alphabet.